# Is this Proof of Well-definedness Correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, exact-sequence, projective-module

[image: here]

I am trying to prove that the function $\bar g$ is well-defined. This is how I did it:

Define $\bar g: \ker\alpha \to \ker\beta$ by $\bar g(m) = g(m)$, for all $m$ in $\ker\alpha$. This means $m$ is in $A$. By commutativity of the square $ABED$, $\beta (g(m)) = j(\alpha(m)) = j(0) = 0$. Hence, $g(m)$ is in $\ker\beta$. Since $m$ is in $\ker\alpha$, then $\bar g(\alpha) = g(m)$. Hence, $\bar g(\alpha)$ is in $\ker\beta$. Hence, $\bar g$ is well-defined.

I want to know if this is a good way to go about it. I will also appreciate it if you could suggest a better approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to give a better exposition to your question. What are A, B, C etc? What are $g,h,j$ etc? Groups ? Rings? Modules?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works exactly like that. Since $ABED$ commutes, i.e. $j\alpha = \beta g$, the map $g$ sends every $m \in \ker \alpha$ inside $\ker \beta$. Define $\bar{g}$ as the restriction of $g$ to $\ker\alpha$ as you did.

Just be careful, you wrote $\bar{g}(\alpha)$ at some point, which doesn't make sense, I think you meant $\bar{g}(m)$.

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing out the error. Also, what if I choose to pick points $x$ and $y$ in ker $\alpha$, where $x = y$, and try to show that $\bar g (x) = \bar g (y)$? This was my first approach, but I didn’t know how to go about it.

Comment: Well, if $x = y$ then surely $\bar g(x) = \bar g(y)$.

Comment: After showing exactness at ker $\beta$, do I need to show exactness at ker $\alpha$ and ker $\gamma$ as well, since by definition the sequence must be exact at all “points”?

Comment: @MrProf If you want the sequence to be exact at $\ker \alpha$ and $\ker \gamma$ then you need to have a morphism going into $\ker \alpha$ and one coming out of $\ker \gamma$, otherwise, it wouldn't make sense to talk about exactness. But yes, you have to show it at every point of the sequence where you have in-going and out-going morphisms.